# How to create cascading dropdown list inside dynamically added table row and save in the database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have added dynamic rows in the table with dropdown lists that are dependent with each other (cascading). I can successfully add dynamic rows with these dropdown lists but the problem is how am I going to populate the values of the second dropdown list (subcategories) based on the selected values in the first dropdown list (categories)? [Please see this image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgY0n.jpg

I can already populate the values in the first dropdown list which has a value from database but I am still looking for a way on how to populate the values in the second dropdown. I have tried to populate data using hard-coded values (see below codes) and it functions right. But when I am fetching the values in the database, that's where I am struggling.

CONTROLLER

```
 //To populate data in second dropdown list
 public ActionResult GetPSESubcategories(Guid pse_category_id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> subCategories = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var subCategoryList = PopulateDropdown.GetPSESubcategory(pse_category_id);
        return Json(subCategoryList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

VIEW

```
<div class="row" style="display:none;" id="patientExperienceDiv">
    <div class="table-responsive" style="padding-left:8px !important;">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                    <text style="font-weight:500 !important;"><strong>II.</strong>&nbsp;Categories</text><br />
                    <text style="font-size:12px;color:#a5a5a5;font-weight:400 !important;">Please select.</text>
                 </th>
                 <th style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                    <text style="font-weight:500 !important">Subcategories</text><br />
                    <text style="font-size:12px;color:#a5a5a5;font-weight:400 !important;">Please select.</text>
                 </th>
                 <th style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;"></th>
                 <th style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;"></th>
                 <th style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;"></th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody id="multipleCategoryTbl">
               <tr>
                 <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                     <div style="padding-top:2px">                                                            
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.addedCategory, new SelectList(ViewBag.PSECategories, "Value", "Text"), "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control", @id ="cat" })
                      </div>
                  </td>
                  <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                     <div style="padding-top:2px;">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.addedSubcategory, new SelectList(ViewBag.PSESubcategories, "Value", "Text"), "Select Subcategory", new { @class = "form-control field", @disabled = "disabled", @id = "sub" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(a => a.addedSubcategory, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control field", @readonly = "readonly", @id = "nature", @style = "display:none;" } })
                      </div>
                   </td>
                   <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                       <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default btn-sm" id="addNewCategoryBtn" style="text-align:center !important;">
                       <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                       </button>
                   </td>
                   <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                       <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default btn-sm" id="removeNewCategoryBtn" onclick="remove_row('multipleCategoryTbl')" style="text-align:center !important;">
                       <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                       </button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="textId" name="ids" value="0" /></td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
   $(function () {
       $('#cat').change(function () {
           getSelectedItem(this, null);
       });

       $('#addNewCategoryBtn').click(function () {
           addRow('multipleCategoryTbl');
       });

       //sample hard-coded values that must be replaced by javascript on cascading dropdown list values from database
       var jsonObj = { "category1": ["subcat 1"], "category2": ["subcat 2.1", "subcat 2.2"], "category3": ["subcat 3.1", "subcat 3.2", "subcat 3.3"] };
       var keys = Object.keys(jsonObj);

       var category_dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");

       var getSelectedItem = function (element, row) {
           $("#sub").prop("disabled", false);

           var e = element;
           var selectedCategory = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
           alert(selectedCategory);    //selected value in the first dropdown list

           var sub_category_dropdown = (row != null ? row.getElementsByTagName("select")[1] : document.getElementById("sub"));

          alert(sub_category_dropdown.nodeValue); //check the values of second dropdown list

          sub_category_dropdown.options.length = 0;

          for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj[selectedCategory].length; i++) {                                                
             sub_category_dropdown[sub_category_dropdown.length] = new Option(jsonObj[selectedCategory][i], jsonObj[selectedCategory][i]);
          }
        };

        //to dynamically add table rows
        var addRow = function (tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        }
        var selects = row.getElementsByTagName("select");
        selects[0].addEventListener('change', function () { getSelectedItem(this, row) }, false);
        };

        //this must be the place where the values of second dropdown is populated
        for (var keys in jsonObj) {                                     
        category_dropdown[category_dropdown.length] = new Option(keys, keys);
        }
   });
```

This is the separate javascript I made for cascading dropdown list but I dont't know where to insert this in the getSelectedItem function

```
$("#cat").on('change', function () {
        alert($(this).val());

        $("#sub").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#sub").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPSESubcategories", "PSERegistry")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { pse_category_id: $(this).val() },
            success: function (subCategories) {
                $("#sub").append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Select Subcategory'));
                $.each(subCategories, function (i, sub) {
                    $("#sub").append('<option value ="' + sub.Value + '">' + sub.Text + '</option>');
                });

                //Update the data in subcategory dropdown upon selection of category
                $("#sub").trigger("chosen:updated");
                $("#sub").trigger("liszt:updated");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Please select Category.');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

UPDATE:

I modified the javascript for cascading dropdown list and this is what I have,

```
<script>

    $('#cat').change(function () {
        alert('test');
        getSelectedItem(this, null);
    });

    var category_dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");

    function getSelectedItem(element, row) {
        $("#sub").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#sub").empty();                                   

        var e = element;
        var selectedCategory = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(selectedCategory);

        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '@Url.Action("GetPSESubcategories", "PSERegistry")',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: { pse_category_id: selectedCategory },
             success: function (subCategories) {

                 var sub_category_dropdown = (row != null ? row.getElementsByTagName("select")[1] : document.getElementById("sub"));
                 sub_category_dropdown.options.length = 0;

                 $("#sub").append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Select Subcategory'));
                 $.each(subCategories, function (i, sub) {

                 sub_category_dropdown[sub_category_dropdown.length] = new Option(sub.Text, sub.Value);
                                                //alert(sub.Value);
                 });
              },
              error: function () {
                 alert('Please select Category.');
              }
           });
         };

         function addRow(table_id) {
            alert('new row added');

            var table = document.getElementById(table_id);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            alert(rowCount);

            for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.innerHTML);
                //alert(newcell.childNodes[0].type);

                switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = rowCount;
                    case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                    case "select":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
                }
             }

             var selects = row.getElementsByTagName("select");
             selects[0].addEventListener('change', function () {
                 alert('clicked');
                 getSelectedItem(this, row)
             }, false);
          }
```

The cascading dropdown inside the dynamically add rows are already functioning but the first row (original row to duplicate during dynamic adding) is affected whenever I select on other dropdown list on other rows.

Can someone help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found the solution on my problem. And this is what I have done,

VIEW

```
<div class="row" style="display:none;" id="patientExperienceDiv">
    <div class="table-responsive" style="padding-left:8px !important;">
        <table class="table" id="pxeTable">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                   <text style="font-weight:500 !important;"><strong>II.</strong>&nbsp;Categories</text><br />
                   <text style="font-size:12px;color:#a5a5a5;font-weight:400 !important;">Please select.</text>
                </th>
                <th style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                    <text style="font-weight:500 !important">Subcategories</text><br />
                    <text style="font-size:12px;color:#a5a5a5;font-weight:400 !important;">Please select.</text>
                 </th>
                 <th style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;"></th>
                 <th style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;"></th>
                 <th style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;"></th>
                 <th style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;"></th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="pxeTbody">
                 <tr>
                    <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                       @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.pxeAddedCategory, new SelectList(ViewBag.PSECategories, "Value", "Text"), "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control pxeCategoryDDL", @id = "pxeCategoryList" })
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.pxeAddedSubcategory, new SelectList(ViewBag.PSESubcategories, "Value", "Text"), "Select Subcategory", new { @class = "form-control pxeSubcategoryDDL", @id = "pxeSubcategoryList" })
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control pxeRowIndex" id="pxeIndexId" name="pxeRowIndexIds" value="0" readonly />
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control pxeConcatField" name="pxeRowConcatField" readonly />
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
                       <button type="button" id="addNewCategoryBtn" class="form-control btn btn-xs btn-default addNewCategory" onclick="addRowPXE('pxeTbody')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add">
                       <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                       </button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;display:none;">
                        <button type="button" id="removeNewCategoryBtn" class="form-control btn btn-xs btn-default removeNewCategory" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
   //cascading dropdown list inside dynamically added rows
   $("#pxeTable").on('change', '.pxeCategoryDDL', function () {
       var table = document.getElementById('pxeTbody');
       var rowCount = table.rows.length;

       var pxeSelectedCategory = $(this).val();
       var row = $(this).closest('tr');                            // get the row
       var pxeSubcatSelect = row.find('.pxeSubcategoryDDL');       // get the other select in the same row
       var pxeRowIndex = row.find('.pxeRowIndex');

       alert(rowCount);
       alert(pxeSelectedCategory);
       //alert(pxeSubcatSelect.innerHTML);

       //pxeSubcatSelect.attr('disabled', false);
       pxeSubcatSelect.empty();
       pxeRowIndex.val(rowCount);

       // make ajax call passing the pxeSelectedCategory to controller. And in the success callback, update the options of pxeSubcatSelect
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '@Url.Action("GetPSESubcategories", "PSERegistry")',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: { pse_category_id: pxeSelectedCategory },
           success: function (subCategories) {
               pxeSubcatSelect.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Select Subcategory'));
               $.each(subCategories, function (i, sub) {
                   pxeSubcatSelect.append('<option value ="' + sub.Value + '">' + sub.Text + '</option>');
              })
           }
        });
        return false;
     });

     //sub category dropdown on change
     $("#pxeTable").on('change', '.pxeSubcategoryDDL', function () {
         var table = document.getElementById('pxeTbody');
         var rowCount = table.rows.length;
         var row = $(this).closest('tr');

         //get the selected values in each dropdown list
         var pxeCategory = row.find('.pxeCategoryDDL').val();
         var pxeSubcategory = row.find('.pxeSubcategoryDDL').val();
         var pxeRowIndex = row.find('.pxeRowIndex').val();
         var pxeConcatField = row.find('.pxeConcatField');

         //concatenate all values and store in hidden text field
         var pxeConcatData = pxeCategory + "," + pxeSubcategory + "," + pxeRowIndex;
         alert(pxeConcatData);
         pxeConcatField.val(pxeConcatData);
      });


      //remove added rows
      $(document).on("click", ".removeNewCategory", function ()     {                                      
          $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // closest used to remove the respective 'tr' in which I have my controls
      });


      //dynamically add row for multiple events
      function addRowPXE(table_id) {
        alert('new pxe row added');
        var table = document.getElementById(table_id);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        alert(rowCount);

        $("#removeNewCategoryBtn").attr('display', 'block');

        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;

            switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
               case "text":
                   newcell.childNodes[0].value = rowCount;
                   break;
               case "select":
                   newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                   break;
             }
           }
        };
    </script>
```